# Simple PHP isset test

Tags: php, ternary-operator

This below does not seem to work how I would expect it, event though $_GET['friendid'] = 55 it is returning NULL

```
<?PHP

$_GET['friendid'] = 55;

$friendid = (!isset($_GET['friendid'])) ? $_GET['friendid'] : 'empty';

echo $friendid;
exit;

?>
```

Comment: It should be echoing 'empty', because you have the expressions in the ternary operator backwards.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Remove the `!`. You don't want to negate the expression.

```
$friendid = isset($_GET['friendid']) ? $_GET['friendid'] : 'empty';
```

Comment: Ok that works however I don't understand why this happens, $_GET['friendid'] = ''; does not show empty, shouldn't this be considered a null value?

Comment: '' is an empty string, but the variable is still set.

Comment: That has nothing to do with sucking, but with the fact that a variable can be declared ($var) or initialized ($var = 'bla'). a non-declared variable and a variable declared and initialized as an empty string is not the same.

Answer (score 71):

As of [PHP 7's release](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/php7timeline), you can use the null-coalescing operator (double "?") for this:

```
$var = $array["key"] ?? "default-value";
// which is synonymous to:
$var = isset($array["key"]) ? $array["key"] : "default-value";
```

In PHP 5.3+, if all you are checking on is a "[truthy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)" value, you can use the "Elvis operator" (note that this does not check isset).

```
$var = $value ?: "default-value";
// which is synonymous to:
$var = $value ? $value : "default-value";
```

Comment: ?:-) uh huh huh

Answer (score 11):

If you're lazy and risky, you can use [error control operator @](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) and short form of [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

```
$friendid = @$_GET['friendid']?: 'empty';
```

Comment: I came here looking for a condensed form of the control structure posted in the answer, and yours is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Just to note that this solution is slower, can interfere with (badly written) custom error handlers, etc and an if statement would execute faster. But that doesn't mean it's evil though.

Answer (score 6):

Currently you're working with the ternary operator:

```
$friendid = (!isset($_GET['friendid'])) ? $_GET['friendid'] : 'empty';
```

Break it down to an `if-else` statement and it looks like this:

```
if(!isset($_GET['friendid']))
   $friendid = $_GET['friendid'];
else
   $friendid = 'empty';
```

Look at what's really happening in the `if` statement:

```
!isset($_GET['friendid'])
```

Note the exclamation mark (!) in front of the `isset` function. It's another way to say, "the opposite of". What you're doing here is checking that there is no value already set in `$_GET['friendid']`. And if so, `$friendid` should take on that value.

But really, it would break since `$_GET['friendid']` doesn't even exist. And you can't take the value of something that isn't there.

Taking it from the start, you have set a value for `$_GET['friendid']`, so that first `if` condition is now false and passes it on to the `else` option.

In this case, set the value of the `$friendid` variable to `empty`.

What you want is to remove the exclamation and then the value of `$friendid` will take on the value of `$_GET['friendid']` if it has been previously set.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution for this question, i.e. if you also need to 'check for the empty string', is [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

```
$friendid = empty($_GET['friendid']) ? 'empty' : $_GET['friendid'];
```

[empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) not only checks whether the variable is set, but additionally returns false if it is fed anything that could be considered 'empty', such as an empty string, empty array, the integer 0, boolean false, ...

Answer (score 1):

From your reply to Philippe I think you need to have a look at the differences between [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

To summarise, `isset()` will return boolean TRUE if the variable exists. Hence, if you were to do

```
$fid = $_GET['friendid'] = "";
$exists = isset($fid);
```

`$exists` will be TRUE as `$_GET['friendid']` exists. If this is not what you want I suggest you look into empty. Empty will return TRUE on the empty string (""), which seems to be what you are expecting. If you do use empty, *please* refer to the documentation I linked to, there are other cases where empty will return true where you may not expect it, these cases are explicitly documented at the above link.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) operator in if condition like this

```
if($myArr['user'] ?? false){
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if(isset($myArr['user']) && $myArr['user']){
```

Answer (score 0):

if friendid is **NOT** set, friendid = friendid otherwise friendid = empty

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I may have been having a similar issue not being familiar with the ! situation as jasondavis had.

Kind of confusing but finding out not having the ! as in... isset($avar) compared to !isset($avar) can make quite the difference.

So with the ! in place, is more stating a YES as in

```
    since $_GET['friendid'] = 55; has been initialized...
                                tell me 'no' - the opposite - that it hasn't and set it to empty.
              $friendid = (!isset($_GET['friendid'])) ? $_GET['friendid'] : 'empty';

    where not having the ! tells me yes it has something in it, leave it be.

               $friendid = (!isset($_GET['friendid'])) ? $_GET['friendid'] : 'empty';
```

Was far less confusing with if A$="" then.... work it. ( or if $A="" for those of PHP ).

I find this use of strings and variables all as strings to be very daunting at times. Even through the confusion, I can actually understand why... just makes things a tad difficult to grasp for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, if I need to know BOTH are true

1. key is set
2. value is truthy

and if not, use another result:

the shortest way is
 `$result = ($arr['b'] ?? 0) ?: $arr['a'];`

(ie. if `b` is_set AND has a real value, use it.  Otherwise use `a`)

So in this scenario:
`$arr = ['a' => 'aaa', 'b' => 'bbb'];`

`$result = 'aaa'`