# How can empty "get" variables be prevented from showing in the url?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a **search form** that has **many fields** and I want the links produced by said form to be as short as possible.
Hence I need to prevent the appearance of empty or undefined variables in the url.

I'll make a short example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="variable_one"/>
    <select name="variable_two">
        <!--options-->
    </select>
    <select name="variable_three">
        <!--options-->
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form!"/>
</form>
```

In this instance, by default, if I were to fill the first field with the string "foo", then submit the form, the url would look like this:

```
example.com/search?variable_one=foo&variable_two=&variable_three=
```

I need the empty variables to be removed, like so:

```
example.com/search?variable_one=foo
```

Empty url variables would have no use in this instance and their removal would make links easier to use, or at least shorter.

I think **javascript** holds the answer, but I currently do not know how to achieve it.

Comment: And why GET an not POST?

Comment: Because, as I described, I want users to be able to share or save their search query, which I think would imply the use of url variables, ergo a GET method.

Comment: JS doesn't actually have access to the generated URL, but you can use some tools to build a queryString from a form, jQuery has it built-in. you might need a replace() call on that to strip empties. you can also remove the name of any empty input onsubmit(), and it should be removed from the key=value pairings.

Comment: This Question, was already asked and got an Answer:

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271525/empty-get-variables-displaying-in-the-url

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `jquery.serialize()` method, then `split` the result string by `&` check if differents parameter has a value and insert in another array if it has, finally `join` the result string using `&` and change the `location.href` using your url and concatenate the result string with your parameters (of course instead of all this `split`,`join`... stuff you can do it with a regex using `string.replace`):

```js
    $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var url = $( this ).serialize();
      var array = url.split('&');
      var resultArray = [];
      for(i in array){
        console.log(array[i].split('='));
        if(array[i].split('=')[1]){
           resultArray.push(array[i]);
        }
      }
      var url_params = resultArray.join('&');
      var yourURL = "http://your_url" + "?" + url_params;
      // do your get...
      alert("location.href to " + yourURL);
      location.href = yourURL;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
        <input type="text" name="variable_one"/>
        <select name="variable_two">
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        <select name="variable_three">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="a">a</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit form!"/>
    </form>
```

Hope this helps,