# Radio value not transfered on acion="#"

Tags: php

I am trying to create a quiz that doesn't changes the page name. I am able to change the content of the page, but at the same time, I am not able to fetch the values of the question and check whether the option is correct or not.
Please tell me where I am making mistake. I want to award 4 marks if the answer is correct and want to deduct 1 mark if the answer is wrong. I'm fetching the questions and options from the database.

Here is the code for quiz.html

```
<html>
<head>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tests";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$id=1;
$sql = "SELECT question, opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,correct FROM quiz where id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $question=$row["question"];
        $opt1=$row["opt1"];
        $opt2=$row["opt2"];
        $opt3=$row["opt3"];
        $opt4=$row["opt4"];
        $correct=$row["correct"];


    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("q2.php");
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
<form action="q2.php" method="POST">
<h3><?php echo $question;?></h3>

<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'><?php echo $opt1;?></br>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'><?php echo $opt2;?></br>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'><?php echo $opt3;?></br>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'><?php echo $opt4;?></br>
</form>
<button type ="submit">Next</button>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for displaying second question and so on..(q2.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tests";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$id=2;
$sql = "SELECT question, opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,correct FROM quiz where id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $question=$row["question"];
        $opt1=$row["opt1"];
        $opt2=$row["opt2"];
        $opt3=$row["opt3"];
        $opt4=$row["opt4"];
        $correct=$row["correct"];


    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();


?>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("result.php");
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
<form action="results.php" method="POST">
<h3><?php echo $question;?></h3>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'><?php echo $opt1;?></br>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'><?php echo $opt2;?></br>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'><?php echo $opt3;?></br>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'><?php echo $opt4;?></br>

</form>
<button>Next</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Now how to display the final result on the page results.php? 
P.S. I am a newbie. Please don't consider me professional.

Comment: Must you display only one question at a time, or are you able to display them all at once if you so choose?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the results to results.php, you will need to have the correct answers fetched from the database and you need to compare them to the inputted answers.

> I am not able to fetch the values of the question and check whether the option is correct or not

Can you elaborate on this? You should be able to grab the post values simply by doing `$_POST['choices']` in your PHP code.

Keep in mind though, that if you do not store the submitted values somehow between page requests, then you're not going to be able to fetch the previous submissions. To clarify, if you submit the first answer on the first page, and then you submit the second answer on the second page, you will not receive the first data a second time - so if you didn't process that data or store it to be processed later, you'll have lost it.

It's because of this that I recommend a different approach compared to what you're doing. Instead of submitting one answer on a different page at a time, you should fetch and display all the questions on one page. If necessary, hide all but one at a time with jQuery, but don't submit anything until the all questions are answered. Then use a jQuery post function to send the form data to results.php to be processed and displayed.

> I want to award 4 marks if the answer is correct and want to deduct 1 mark if the answer is wrong.

This will all need to be done in the results.php code. If you want to store the data of who got what questions right/wrong, then you need to store that information in a table (**not** the same table as the one your questions are stored in). Also, remember that you need to make the `$id` variable dynamic, unless you want everyone to have the same results.

Comment: I used sessions to store the value of the response. I also added 
 $choice= $_POST['choices']; on page q2.php but it showed an error like undefined variable choices.

Comment: Please run the code and check. The values are not fetched. Please tell me what all code I need to append in my files to get the quiz working. 
Loading whole quiz on a single page would take a lot of time to load the quiz as the quiz contain images too.

Comment: For the undefined warning you're getting, it's because you need to check if the value is set before trying to fetch it. Look into ternary operators. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248864/simple-php-isset-test

Comment: You also did not post the results.php code, so I cannot run the code in full.

Comment: What I want is, to display the value of selected option on q2.php 
So i wrote : 
$m=$_GET['choices'];
echo $m;

But It is not echoing the value of the choice that was selected on quiz.php . How to display the value of the selected choice on quiz.php on q2.php ? What I want to do is, check that whether the selected option is correct or not. That's it. How to do that?

Comment: That won't work because your form has `method="post"` (as it should), so you need to access the data with `$m = $_POST['choices'];` instead of using `$_GET['choices']`. You would use `$_GET` if the form method was set to `get`. Alternatively, you can use `$_REQUEST['choices']` to work for either form method, but it is recommended to use what your form's method is set to.