# empty text input means empty $_POST[] element? (Null coallesce)

Tags: php, post, null-coalescing

So my question is:

If I don't write anything in an input

```
<input type="text" name="test">
```

in a simple form with post method, when I receive the `$_POST` array in my action url, the `$_POST["test"]` exists as empty string (`$_POST["test"] => ""`).

So I can't use *null coalesce* because `$var = $_POST["test"] ?? 'default';` because it is always `$var = "";` (as is normal).

Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: `isset()` is the function to write in your condition.  Did you have a look around StackOverflow before posting this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if $\_POST exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496971/check-if-post-exists)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? The ternary operator: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1248864/2125723

Answer (score 1):

**for Only check if a PARTICULAR Key is available in post data**

```
if (isset($_POST['test']) )
{
    $textData = '+text'.$_POST['test'];
    echo $textData;
}
```

Comment: Golly, why didn't I post that answer?  Did you see that I posted a duplicate link?  Did you check that before you offered your answer?  StackOverflow doesn't _need_ more questions/pages.  It needs unique questions/pages.  Please help this community by filtering out the duplicates.

Comment: And now you are getting upvotes -- which will encourage you to post answers to duplicate questions.

Comment: You can actually start doing the right thing, right now, right here.  There are millions of legitimate questions to answer here.  Try to earn your rep from questions that are unique.